# Sed to edit multiple patterns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Is there a way to change multiple (up to ten) patterns in a single fasta file using sed?
For instance I want to change X for Y:

```
sed "s/X/Y/g" < file1.fasta > output.fasta
```

how to add `sed "s/\s/_/g"` and 8 more commands to the same one-liner?

Comment: Doesn't fasta wrap lines, so this would be incorrect anyway; and what do you expect the bash, awk and python tags to achieve here?

Comment: Are you replacing all single characters every time?

Comment: I usually change the .fasta extension to .txt and then manipulate it with bash

Comment: some of them are single characters, some are regular expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate the commands by semicolons

```
sed 's/a/b/;s/c/d/'
```

(you can also use newlines instead of semicolons)

or you can use multiple `-e`s:

```
sed -e 's/a/b/' -e 's/c/d/'
```

Answer (score 3):

see this example: (test with gnu sed):

```
kent$ echo 'abcd'|sed 's/a/1/;s/b/2/;s/c/3/;s/d/4/' 
1234

kent$  echo 'abcd'|sed 'y/abcd/1234/'               
1234
```